# Android - Saving state through static variables

Tags: android, bitmap, save, instance, state

I know this question has already been asked, and i read about saving state through static variables is bad practice. BUT..

My problem is that i have a big bitmap to handle at runtime, and it has to be a bit modified whenever screen orientation changes..
Creating a bitmap throught:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
```

is a bit expensive, and my orientation change gets pretty slow.

NOW, since the first thing i want to avoid is memory leaks, how should i manage this?

I know that this reference can be destroyed if OS kills my process but my code just checks if this variable exists and is "on", if not it recreates it. So no problems at all.

Is this a good practice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind with the third party frameworks, you can try [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

A perfect framework for handling images in Android apps and very easy to use. It can handle `Activity` life cycle,load images from background, memory and disk caching, Bitmap and resource pooling to minimize jank and many more. I hope it will simplify your work.